# modified .htaccess file doesn't work with BrowserMatchNoCase

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The servers (Ubuntu Server) it's going down because a 360Spider it's running too many request per seconds, I am trying to resolve this using this configuration in the .htaccess file:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase "360Spider" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase ^360Spider bots

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bots
```

And works partially because the error.log logs some of this events:

```
[Sun Jul 20 23:30:15 2014] [error] [client 10.183.200.5] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/view, referer: http://www.mysite.org/
```

But the access.log it's still saving information about the 360Spider:

```
10.183.200.5 - - [20/Jul/2014:23:31:33 -0400] "GET /view/article/154967 HTTP/1.1" 403 536 "http://www.mysite.org/view/article/154967/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0); 360Spider"
```

I want to block all that have the word 360Spider.

PD: I can't block the bot using the ip because all the traffic come with the same ip. I just can work with the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Any IP Address, or bot going to a url/website will most likely make a `GET` request — **Apache logs it**. Just because you see it in the log does not mean it isn't blocked; **Your access.log clearly shows that it is**.

When the bot tried to `GET /view/article/154967` it was denied ([**403 Forbidden**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).